# Java to instantiate a class dynamically based on a string name

Tags: java, android

ok so this has been asked many times and I have looked at various answers but still somehow not able to get this right.

Problem:
I have some 5 fragments(non android guys please assume classes) which I need to dynamically instantiate based on what is clicked in a list. I get the string in the click handler. I have named my fragments conveniently. So basically one of my fragments is called SearchResults.java and the corresponding item click will return "SearchResults". So I want to do something like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Class cls = Class.forname(clickedString)   //clickedString = "SearchResults"
//instantiate it as if it were equal to SearchResults sr = new SearchResults().
}
```

I just want to avoid if/ else or switch cases and looking for a smarter way. I might be missing some very basic core java concepts. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java

Comment: putting a comment here after some 4 years just in case someone lands up. Fragments should never be instantiated with a constructor.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654766/creating-a-fragment-constructor-vs-newinstance.
For a generic class loading by name, reflection is the way. see Asterisk's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need fully qualified class names, i.e: `your.full.class.path.SearchResults`, after that it becomes relatively easy to instantiate assuming a no-args constructor:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(clickedString);
SearchResults results = (SearchResults) cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Both `newInstance()` and `getDeclaredConstructor()` optionally take in the argument and argument types respectively.

Comment: so you mean clickedString has to be a fully qualified classname? And as luck would have it, my fragments already have a newInstance method. More of a factory thing. Hope that is called and not the default one.

Comment: It would work for me I guess. Except that my fragments already have a static 'newInstance' method.

Comment: The method is called forName not forname.

Comment: `newInstance()` is deprecated since version 9. What is the current way to do this?

Comment: @RichardNeumann `Class.newInstance` is deprecated as it bypasses constructor code. But `Constructor.newInstace` is fine.