# What's the right way to inflate a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I've been doing it like this for a while, is it the right way?

**Activity:**

```
    public void toSettings(){
    Fragment_Settings frag = new Fragment_Settings();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContainer, frag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
```

**In some listener in another fragment:**

```
((Activity_Main)getActivity()).toSettings();
```

Comment: IMHO There is nothing wrong communicating through the hosting Activity in this instance, although I tend to use interfaces. If you were using a FragmentManager in a Fragment it would be getChildFragmentManager - an example would be having a Fragment with a nested ViewPager. As I say, my opinion, others may vary. I could argue however, that seeing as it's a settings screen it has relevance to being in its own Activity instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.addToBackStack(null)` Just delete that piece and your fragment will not be added to backstack. I would also suggest adding a TAG to the replace method just in case you want to retrieve the fragment later. Something like this `.replace(R.id.mainContainer, frag, TAG)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct but i have some suggestions.

1. If you wanna back previous fragment from `Fragment_Settings` use `add` method instead of `replace` and `addToBackStack("tag of Fragment_Settings")` instead of `addToBackStack(null)`.
2. `newInstance` pattern is more preferred than `Fragment_Settings frag = new Fragment_Settings();`. You can see some explanations about that.
   http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html
   [Creating a Fragment: constructor vs newInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654766/creating-a-fragment-constructor-vs-newinstance)
3. To avoid code repetition when navigating between fragments you can use a manager class provides organizing add, replace or pop processes.
   [Here is my navigation manager class](https://gist.github.com/faranjit/049fc068f76ab75065248552beafb198).