# Android - How to Pass Extra data with Intent to ListFragment?

Tags: java, android

I get an error when I want to transfer a string using "intenet put extra", it seems that the second activity fails delivered

MainActivity

public void AbrirLista() {

```
    Conversation conversationForUserList = pagerAdapter.getItem(pager.getCurrentItem()); 


    if (conversationForUserList.getType() == Conversation.TYPE_CHANNEL) {                   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(
                Extra.USERS,
                binder.getService().getConnection(server.getId()).getUsersAsStringArray(conversationForUserList.getName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_USERS);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.only_usable_from_channel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

```
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerView);
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends ListFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final String[] users = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(Extra.USERS);
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    }


}
```

Comment: `SecondActivity` is `ListFragment` fragment not Activity so use `FragmentManager` to add fragment in Current Activity instead of `startActivityForResult`

Comment: try to extends ListActivity instead of ListFragment.

Comment: startActivity(intent);

Comment: You can get the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387740/where-how-to-getintent-getextras-in-an-android-fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
   Conversation conversationForUserList = pagerAdapter.getItem(pager.getCurrentItem()); 
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("name_id",conversationForUserList);
    startActivity(intent);

    // get data to SecondActivity.class
    private Context context;
    private Conversation userList;
    private ArrayList<Conversation> users;
    userList = (Conversation) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("name_id");
    users=conversationForUserList.getName(context);

     ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
      setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
```