# Change button text in activity depending upon intent

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I am new to Android programming.

I have an activity with two options "Book Test drive" and "Buy Car". When I click on "book test drive", I am taken to a gridview and then to MainActivity 5. I want the text on MainActivity 5's button to remain as "book test drive" when I click on "book test drive", but change to "get on road price" when I click on buy car. The button's layout lies in the ImageAdapter Fragment. How do I go about this?

getIntent.getExtras does not work in a Fragment Activity.
I am sending data in the form of `intent.putExtra("", "");`.

Comment: @an13892, search on google - How to pass data by intent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387740/where-how-to-getintent-getextras-in-an-android-fragment

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you have to use

```
 getArguments.getExtra(KEY);
```